# Не реагировать на Throwable в Unit тестах

Tags: android, юнит-тесты, junit, mockito

Использую:

1. Mockito (3.4.0)
2. JUnit4
3. LiveData (android arch components)
4. ViewModel (android arch components)
5. RxJava

Тест настроен следующим образом

```
    @get:Rule
    var rule: TestRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        val hook = object : RxAndroidSchedulersHook() {
            override fun getMainThreadScheduler(): Scheduler {
                return Schedulers.trampoline()
            }
        }
        RxAndroidPlugins.getInstance().registerSchedulersHook(hook)
        RxJavaHooks.setOnNewThreadScheduler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
        RxJavaHooks.setOnIOScheduler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
        RxJavaHooks.setOnComputationScheduler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
    
    }
```

Необходимо протестировать следующий код(момент попадания в блок catch):

```
interactor.getData()
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .doOnSubscribe { state.value = State.Loading }
    .subscribe({ 
        state.value = State.Data(items = it)
    }, {
        state.value = State.Error
    })
```

Мне нужно протестировать, что если в Рх цепочке произошел Exception, то `LiveData` "state" приняла значение `State.Error` (но у меня тест сразу отваливается т.к. произошел экзепшен)

Как все таки протестировать?